# How do I check if the window has scrolled to a href and then execute a function in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this [accordian](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/) and I have a link on an external page, (see below).

I would simply like when the user clicks on that external link, a specific accordion section would open on the new page (`page2.html` in this case). (I know you can have a area open of your choosing in the default section of the .js but that's different).

I tried this.

The link on the external page.

```
<a href="page2.html#Education">foo</a>
```

Set up an ID on the page with the accordion.

```
<a id="Education" href="#Education">Education<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
```

And some jQuery on the accordion page to handle that selection.

```
$(function() {
    $('#st-accordion').accordion();
    if ($('a[href="#Education"]') == $(window.location.hash)) {
         $('#st-accordion').accordion();
       // I also have tried calling the `accordion();` on the `$('a[href="#Education"]')` to activate it.
    }
});
```

I am close, sort of. All I get is when the user clicks from the external page, the user get pushed down to the correct link, but I can't get it to uncollapse).

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I tried this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#st-accordion').accordion();

    $('#Education').focus(function() {
        console.log('test'); // <-- This worked in the console.

       $('a[href="#Education').accordion({open:2}); // <-- This did not.

    });
});
```

Comment: What is the point of the two oneOpenedItem statements? If `$(location.hash) == internship`, then you just end up calling it twice. If it's false then you cal it anyway.

Comment: I actually left in there while I was testing it. But thanks for your helpful comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to do the following in order to get this to work.

Add a link to the external page i.e. the link which will be taking you to the page which houses the accordion.

```
<a href="externalPage.html?panel=5#st-accordion">Link to accordian page</a>
```

The `panel` in the URL will be assigned a value which will be passed to a function (see below) which will be housed on your host page i.e. the page with the accordion. The hash represents the ID of for your accordion method.

This value represents the section of the accordion you'd like to open on page load.

The following goes on your page which houses your accordion (naturally!).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
    $("#st-accordion").accordion({
        open: defaultPanel,
        collapsible: true
    });

    function getParam(name) {
        var query = location.search.substring(1);
        if (query.length) {
            var parts = query.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
                if (parts[i].substring(0, pos) == name) {
                    return parts[i].substring(pos + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

});
</script>
```

The variable will contain the value which will also be your section/panel number...

```
   var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
```

So if you assigned 0 to the `panel` variable that would be your making your first section uncollapse on page load.

```
<a href="externalPage.html?panel=0#st-accordion">Link to accordian page</a>
```

In theory, using this method would work on any accordion, provided one of the defaults (properties) of the plugin accepts a value to control the opening of specific panels.

```
open: defaultPanel // This variable is housing the function which is being passed the `panel` value. Using our recent example, that would be 0!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="edu" name="Education" href="#">SomeText</a>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#edu").focus(function(){
        alert("Do what do you need here!");
      });      
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Checkout this link to get alert: http://jsbin.com/cuzatejohu#Education

Check this -without #Education-: http://jsbin.com/cuzatejohu#Eyhj

Comment: Hey thanks so much, while I got a `console.log` to fire, I got not much else.

Comment: There is a typo in your `a` selector.

Comment: Checkout [this DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nizuxe/1/#Education) in which section 1 will be opened by default and then section 4 is loaded. By the way, accordion doesn't has property called `open` it is just named `active` as shown in the section 2 of the demo.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I think essentially my problem is I didn't use the official `jQuery .accordion` I found this one and it doesn't have much config options http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/